# string indices must be integers, not str tweepy

Tags: python, json, stream, tweepy, tweets

Hi I am trying to save only the text and coordinates to json from twitter stream,
It works fine when on_status i use self.output.write(status) but when trying to write specific features drops the "string indices must be integers, not str" error. Any ideas for help? Thanks!

The code is based on this tutorial http://badhessian.org/2012/10/collecting-real-time-twitter-data-with-the-streaming-api/

```
class SListener(StreamListener):

def __init__(self, api = None, fprefix = 'streamer'):
    self.api = api or API()
    self.counter = 0
    self.fprefix = fprefix
    self.output  = open(fprefix + '.' 
                        + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
    self.delout  = open('delete.txt', 'a')

def on_data(self, data):

    if  'in_reply_to_status' in data:
        self.on_status(data)
    elif 'delete' in data:
        delete = json.loads(data)['delete']['status']
        if self.on_delete(delete['id'], delete['user_id']) is False:
            return False
    elif 'limit' in data:
        if self.on_limit(json.loads(data)['limit']['track']) is False:
            return False
    elif 'warning' in data:
        warning = json.loads(data)['warnings']
        print warning['message']
        return false

def on_status(self, status):

    self.output.write("\t".join([status['text'], status['text']['coordinates']]) + "\n")        
    self.counter += 1

    if self.counter >= 1000:
        self.output.close()
        self.output = open(self.fprefix + '.' 
                           + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
        self.counter = 0

    return

def on_delete(self, status_id, user_id):
    self.delout.write( str(status_id) + "\n")
    return

def on_limit(self, track):
    sys.stderr.write(track + "\n")
    return

def on_error(self, status_code):
    sys.stderr.write('Error: ' + str(status_code) + "\n")
    return False

def on_timeout(self):
    sys.stderr.write("Timeout, sleeping for 60 seconds...\n")
    time.sleep(60)
    return
```

Comment: Can you include the full text of the error?

Comment: ---> 43         self.output.write("\t".join([status['text'], status['text']['coordinates']]) + "\n")

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str   /// that's the full text, any idea?

Comment: So what it looks like is that the argument `status` you're passing to `on_status` is a string, so you can't do `status['text']`